# Parse HTML which has inline event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, jquery-selectors

I am building a chrome extension, in which i needed to fetch and parse some html from a web page. Decided to use jquery for that.

```
$(htmlString).find(".some-table");
```

The problem is i am getting following warning when running this code.

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

It seems "htmlString" contains some inline event handlers and while parsing it, chrome is throwing this warning.
I cannot control what is inside "htmlString", just needed to retrieve some information out of it. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Does this stop it from working, or is it really just a warning?

Comment: Are you certain this operation _specifically_ causes his?

Comment: @JuanMendes These are just warning (modified question accordingly).

Comment: @Xan after putting some debugging, found out that line 5089 of jquery-2.1.1.js "tmp.innerHTML = wrap[ 1 ] + elem.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" ) + wrap[ 2 ];" is causing the warnings. Basically when htmlString is assigned to innerHTML property of tmp.

Comment: If it's just a warning, why do you care? You just don't want it to show up in the console?

Comment: @JuanMendes Warnings exist for a reason. In this case, Chrome already blocks some vulnerabilities due to bad coding, and helpfully shows a warning. Shrugging off this as "it is just a warning, why do you care" is bad advice. Script injections are blocked, but another class of issues is not. And when this practice is applied outside the context of Chrome extensions, e.g. in a web page, then the application IS vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: @RobW But the OP has no control over the content, and the inline scripts aren't going to be run anyway. If this was used outside of a Chrome extension, I would agree with you.

Comment: @JuanMendes Have you read my answer to the duplicate question? It is very possible to parse HTML in a safe way (without jQuery), so that should be used instead. In my previous comment, by "vulnerable web page", I'm referring to any web page which takes input from untrusted sources (whether retrieved from AJAX, or whether given by another user or external database) and uses jQuery to parse the result.

Comment: @RobW Now I did, and yes, I do agree that not inserting the element into the DOM and stripping event setting attributes sounds better. There are other ways to inject strips, though, such as setting the src of iframes, images to `javascript` so the solution would not be foolproof?

Comment: @JuanMendes Let's assume the following scenario: You have untrusted input, and you want to parse this input as HTML, and use DOM selector APIs to grab some text from it. For that scenario, the presented solution is 100% fool-proof. There is no way for this untrusted input to inject scripts, setting srcs or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit [`$.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/). Quoting the docs:

> Most jQuery APIs that accept HTML strings will run scripts that are included in the HTML. `jQuery.parseHTML` does not run script in the parsed HTML unless `keepScripts` is explicitly true.

However, even doing this is not secure.

> However, it is still possible in most environments to execute script indirectly, for example via the `<img onerror>` attribute. The caller should be aware of this and guard against it by cleaning or escaping any untrusted inputs from sources such as the URL or cookies.

So while it may help for a particular input, you should consider whether such explicit creation of DOM nodes is what you really need. It creates all kinds of nasty edge cases, potentially.